# Acessar com um outro usuário no postgres

Tags: postgresql

Como faço para acessar pelo terminal o meu *postgres* com um outro usuário que tenho criado sem ser o *postgres*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o psql:

```
psql -h HOST -U USUARIO -W
```

Veja alguns links úteis:

- [Resumo de comandos úteis do PostgreSQL](http://blog.lucascaton.com.br/index.php/2010/05/23/resumo-de-comandos-uteis-do-postgresql/)
- [Comandos básicos de psql via SSH](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Comandos_b%C3%A1sicos_de_psql_via_SSH)
- [PostgreSQL: comandos básicos](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/PostgreSQL-comandos-basicos)